# How do I change the hotkey combo to lock the screen

Tags: macbook-pro

On my Macbook pro (OS X 10.8.2) the hotkey combo to lock he screen is Ctrl+Shift+Eject.

I don't like that combination at all.  I'd like to make it Ctrl+Command+l is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using KeyRemap4MacBook, you could add this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

`<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::L, VK_CONTROL | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_EJECT, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT</autogen>`

Comment: I installed KeyRemap4MacBook.  I added this to private.xml.  I rebooted.  However it doesn't seem to do anything.  No new options appear and Ctrl+Command+l does nothing.

Comment: Ok so I found the problem. Your code is incomplete.  You need a buch of other xml stuff

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>

<item><name>Lock Screen with Ctrl+Command+l</name>
<identifier>private.locksreen</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::L, VK_CONTROL | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_EJECT, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT</autogen>
</item>
</root>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest :

1. Create a new service with automator with a "Run Shell Script"
2. Here the script `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`
3. Bind this new service to a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences » Keyboard » pane Keyboard Shortcuts

Edit : [This post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/45740/fast-user-switching-apple-menu/46308#46308) explains it better than me.